# Column that is dependent on a subquery that is dependent on another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, syntax

Alright, I'm relatively new to SQL and Databases. I've been learning for the last two months or so starting with SQLite and now I'm using MS SQL 2008 in my job. I have come across a problem that in theory shouldn't be hard, but I'm running into brick wall with SQL's syntax and structure.

I thought I got used to the logic behind it, but then I get errors that catch me by surprise. So you may see a string of questions from me on SO. Haha.

Anyways, here is what I have in a nutshell:

Huge database with many tables and columns.

I have a query (Q1) that gives me data in this form that is obtained from different tables:

```
id | Info1 | Info2 | Info3 |... | InfoN
1  | ..... | ..... |  20   |... | .....
2  | ..... | ..... |  56   |... | .....
3  | ..... | ..... |  32   |... | .....
4  | ..... | ..... |  17   |... | .....
5  | ..... | ..... |  12   |... | .....
6  | ..... | ..... |  23   |... | .....
```

What I want to do is add another column, "Date1" that depends on the following: Take info from column "id" to run another query (Q2) that gives me data (Here I am using the second row where id = 2):

```
id | Date1 | Date2 | ... | OtherinfoN | Qty 
2  | 03/25 | ..... | ... | .......... | 10
2  | 03/27 | ..... | ... | .......... | 6
2  | 03/26 | ..... | ... | .......... | 54
2  | 03/30 | ..... | ... | .......... | 2
```

Now this query has the data ordered by column "Date2". With that said, I'd like to use the "Info3" data from the original table (for id = 2, it would be Info3 = 56) to figure out at what "Date1" does the Qty add up to or exceed this Info3 number.

To spell out what I'm saying:

- I would look at Qty starting at the top.
- Does 10 = 56, no.
- Then move to the next line, does 10 + 6 = 56, no.
- Then move to the next line, does 10 + 6 + 54 = 56, YES!
- Stop, look at the "Date1" and that would be the value for the "Date1" column in the first column. (03/26)

So the final result should give me which I'll query 3 (Q3):

```
id | Info1 | Info2 | Info3 |... | InfoN | Date1
1  | ..... | ..... |  20   |... | ..... | .....
2  | ..... | ..... |  56   |... | ..... | 03/26
3  | ..... | ..... |  32   |... | ..... | .....
4  | ..... | ..... |  17   |... | ..... | .....
5  | ..... | ..... |  12   |... | ..... | .....
6  | ..... | ..... |  23   |... | ..... | .....
```

Hope I made myself clear.

I thought the structure would look something like this:

```
SELECT (Columns from Q1), Date1 
FROM (SELECT etc from Q1) 
JOIN (SELECT etc from Q2 maybe more nested SELECT statements)
```

But obviously I don't know SQL enough to make this work. It is really tricky trying to learn something new and also applying it at a high quality level.

If anyone can help me with any part of my question, I'd appreciate it. I'm very good at piecing things together from different solutions. So I'll take any piece of advice.

Comment: What you need for the query for the Q2 is running total, to pick the first row where `sum(Qty) over (partition by id order by youroderingcriteria)` is equal or greater than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find records in where the running total of Qty in Q2 is greater than the info3 value for Q1.

[Window functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) are very handy for this kind of query:

```
select *
from   (
          select Q1.*,
                 Q2.Date1,
                 sum( Q2.Qty ) over( partition by Q2.id order by Q2.Date1 ) as running_total
          from   Q1
                 left join
                 Q2
                 on Q1.id = Q2.id
       ) as running_total_query
 where running_total >= info3
```

Example SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6660a/3)

Comment: I'm sorry for not marking it as answered. I'm not sure why. Your answer did help me at the time a great ton. Thanks!